# Is there any way to add windows maximize animation using compiz

Tags: compiz

I am using ubuntu 13.10 unity. Is there any way to modify maximize (not unminimize) using compiz? I mean windows animation when an application goes to full screen state.

Answer (score 2):

The `wobbly windows` option in `compizconfig-settings-manager` will give you an awesome Maximizing Effect.
P.S. This won't work with apps that use full-screens.

Comment: But there is no option for full screen.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: As an example run a media player (vlc) and double click on it. media player will go to full screen mode. F11 for firefox or chrome. Full screen transaction is not smooth, at least for my laptop. I want to add an smooth animation on this transaction.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is associated with the app, if the app says it shouldn't be smooth it will not, and you can't do anything about it. sorry

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add that?